# Why is _IELinkClickByText not working how I expect it to?

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm a first time user of Auto IT and I'm trying to click on a link on a webpage. On the webpage there is a label called "New Business (NB) Quotation"
I want to click it so this is what I'm doing

```
Local $oIE = _IE_Example("basic")

_IELinkClickByText($oIE,"New Business (NB) Quotation")
```

This opens up a different webpage and I get confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://yoururl.com/path")

_IELinkClickByText($oIE,"New Business (NB) Quotation")
```